# Defining a classpath for a Jython virtual environment

Tags: python, jython, virtualenv, bottle

I have installed [Jython](http://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Jython), a [virtualenv](http://pypi.python.org/pypi/virtualenv) named "jython-env" and have installed "bottle" for doing some web application development. I have to use some JAR files in this application for consumption by some Python code. I know I have to set the classpath which should include these JAR files. I tried setting the classpath using

```
export classpath=/home/myname/jclasses/foo.jar
```

but when I try to import the class, it says *module not found*. I am very new at Java and am doing this for the first time.

Can't the configuration be done such that I can just put the JAR files in the sitepackages directory of my virtualenv and use it from there?

Answer (score 6):

```
jython -Dpython.path=/path/to/myjar.jar
```

Here's another idea: you could use a `.pth` file.

Create a file - `/path/to/jythonenv/Lib/site-packages/myjars.pth`:

```
path/to/jar1.jar
path/to/jar2.jar
```

Would also do the trick.

Answer (score 3):

I'd like to suggest [jip](http://pypi.python.org/pypi/jip) for you. With jip, you can manage your Java dependencies and classpath just like pip does for you.

```
pip install jip
```

Install a JAR file with dependencies,

```
jip install org.springframework:spring-core:3.0.5.RELEASE
```

Run with classpath configured,

```
jython-all your-python-file.py
```

Check http://pypi.python.org/pypi/jip for details.